# How will an object with a value type and reference type be stored in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, class

In .NET, integer data type is a value type(stack) and String is a reference type(heap).

So If a class A has an integer, and a string type object in it, and a class B creates an object of class A, then how will this object of class A be stored in memory? In stack, or in a heap?

This was asked in my Microsoft interview. Need to understand how I fared.

Comment: Become familiar with the phrase "implementation detail."

Comment: Can you explain why you care? Suppose I told you that it was stored on the "frob", a special storage location that was neither the stack nor the heap. What *decision* would you make differently knowing that? What follow-up questions about the nature of the "frob" would you ask?

Comment: Well it was an interview question from a company I appeared at. So I was wondering how I fared against what I said there. Eric, thanks for the great article!

Comment: in that vein, think about it in the context of what you asked. They used fields of `int` and `string` to confuse the question, but the question was *really* about class `A`. `A`, being a class, is a reference type. Its fields do not matter. An object of type `A`, therefore, will go on the heap *as per Microsoft's implementation of C# on the desktop CLR*, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eric Lippert [just wrote about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx):

> It is simply false that the choice of whether to use the stack or the heap has anything fundamentally to do with the type of the thing being stored.

The true story is:

> "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

Most importantly, he stresses that you simply **should not care** where a *type* lives. You should care where *things of a certain lifetime* live.

Answer (score 3):

*In general*, only value types that are *local variables* end up on the stack. The rest, including fields of classes, is stored on the heap.

In fact, the situation is more complex; see the link to Eric Lippert's Blog provided in Rex M's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Objects are always reference types, regardless of their member types.

So, any object of Class A will be stored on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a tricky question. I think the question was asked to you to check your knowledge about classes in dotnet. Classes are reference type. So in simple words it will go to the heap section.